# Female supervising men in Factory

Tags: sharia, women, business, men

My wife is planning to establish a pure water factory. In the Factory 75% of the workers will be men, while she supervise/manage them. What is the ruling regarding these issue.Kindly site references for me to buttress the position, please.
If the the ruling is against it, kindly give us examples of  businesess allowed for women to participate in.
Jazakalla khair!

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam.SE, this is not a fatwa site and most of the answerers are not scholars or sheikhs that you are looking for. Take a look at [this link](http://islam.stackexchange.com/about) to know what is going on here.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing in Islam that prevents a woman to supervise men working under her. Remember that the Prophet himself worked for a woman, Khadeeja, who would later become his wife.

Another reported case that came later was that the caliph Omar ibn Al-Khattab appointed a woman as the supervisor of the local market.

Comment: That was pre-islamic though. A big difference. After Islam, there isn't a single case where a women lead?